# Mover múltiples archivos JS de carpeta A a carpeta B (Laravel Mix)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-mix

a todos.

Estoy realizando un proyecto pero tengo un atasco al mover varios archivos `JavaScript` de la carpeta *`resources/assets/js/`* a la carpeta *`public/assets/js/`* usando **Laravel Mix**.

Lo estoy tratando de mover de la siguiente manera, pero solo se mueve uno solo archivo que es el primero. Al parecer solo puede recibir un valor pero no encuentro como lograrlo en varios.

También probé con `mix.copy` como está en la documentación, pero me dice que `copy` no está definido.

¿Alguien tiene alguna forma de hacer esto?

**webpack.mix.js**:

```
js([
    'resources/assets/js/code.js',
    'resources/assets/js/code1.js',
    'resources/assets/js/code2.js',
    'resources/assets/js/code3.js',
    'resources/assets/js/code4.js'
], 'public/assets/js')
```

Answer (score 2):

El método `js` de mix recibe la ruta de un archivo o un arreglo de éstas, y un destino (si el destino es una carpeta, se asume que la salida se llama igual que el origen) y lo que hace es transpilar el origen  con todas las dependencias que esté utilizando por *import* si es ES6,  o *require* si es CommonJS. Si le pasas un arreglo de orígenes, el archivo final contendrá la concatenación de la transpilación de cada elemento del arreglo.

Esto aparece en el repo de Mix: en [types/index.d.ts#L115-L120](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/types/index.d.ts#L115-L120)

```
    /**
     * Compile modern javascript
     *
     * `src` may be a glob pattern
     **/
    js(src: string | string[], output: string): Api;
```

Si lo que quieres es copiar un conjunto de archivos lo correcto sería usar, por ejemplo:

```
mix.copy([
    'resources/assets/js/code.js',
    'resources/assets/js/code1.js',
    'resources/assets/js/code2.js',
    'resources/assets/js/code3.js',
    'resources/assets/js/code4.js'
], 'public/assets/js')
```

Si quieres un directorio completo, es más eficiente hacer:

```
mix.copyDirectory(
    'resources/assets/js', 
    'public/assets/js'
)
```

En el mismo link que te puse arriba, la definición de la interfaz es

```
    /** Copy files specified by `from` and place them in `to` */
    copy(from: string | string[], to: string): Api;

    /** Copy files specified by `from` and place them in `to` */
    copyDirectory(from: string | string[], to: string): Api;
```

Si te fijas, esta vez el segundo parámetro no es `output` (un archivo de salida) sino `to`, (un directorio destino).